# SSRS Switch Function and date concatenation

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a text field that I'm trying to condtionaly set. I'm new to SSRS and have not sued the Switch Function before. What I'm trying to do is use the function to give me the Month and then concatenate the year - 1 (so last year) to the end of the Month name. I have included the code that is working to give me the month, but I'm not sure how to get the year added to the end.

Thanks for any help.

```
=Switch(
Month(Today) = "1", "January",
Month(Today) = "2", "February",
Month(Today) = "3", "March",
Month(Today) = "4", "April",
Month(Today) = "5", "May",
Month(Today) = "6", "June",
Month(Today) = "7", "July",
Month(Today) = "8", "August",
Month(Today) = "9", "September",
Month(Today) = "10", "October",
Month(Today) = "11", "November",
Month(Today) = "12", "December"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use & symbol to concatenate the two String.

=Switch( Month(Today) = "1", "January", Month(Today) = "2", "February", Month(Today) = "3", "March", Month(Today) = "4", "April", Month(Today) = "5", "May", Month(Today) = "6", "June", Month(Today) = "7", "July", Month(Today) = "8", "August", Month(Today) = "9", "September", Month(Today) = "10", "October", Month(Today) = "11", "November", Month(Today) = "12", "December" ) & =Other Function.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `& " " & (Year(Today)-1)` to your existing expression, so that it becomes:

```
=Switch(
Month(Today) = "1", "January",
Month(Today) = "2", "February",
Month(Today) = "3", "March",
Month(Today) = "4", "April",
Month(Today) = "5", "May",
Month(Today) = "6", "June",
Month(Today) = "7", "July",
Month(Today) = "8", "August",
Month(Today) = "9", "September",
Month(Today) = "10", "October",
Month(Today) = "11", "November",
Month(Today) = "12", "December"
)
& " " & (Year(Today)-1)
```

However, it would generally be easier to set up an expression as

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Today())
```

(to get the corresponding date from a year ago), and then set the Format property (in the Properties window) to be `MMMM yyyy`.